# Need to make a specific row change color based on a condition

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make a conditional code statement making certain boxes change color based on the condition of another box.

```
 Option Explicit
 Sub QuarterSalesData()

 Dim Qtr_1 As Integer
 Dim Qtr_2 As Integer
 Dim Qtr_3 As Integer
 Dim Qtr_4 As Integer
 Dim One_Total As Integer

 Range("Q2").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-15]+RC[-14]+RC[-13]"
Range("Q2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q2:Q21"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("Q2:Q21").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q2:Q41"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("Q2:Q41").Select

 Range("R2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-13]+RC[-12]+RC[-11]"
Range("R2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("R2:R41"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("R2:R41").Select

  Range("S2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]+RC[-10]+RC[-9]"
Range("S2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("S2:S41"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("S2:S41").Select

Range("T2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-9]+RC[-8]+RC[-7]"
Range("T2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("T2:T41"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("T2:T41").Select
```

Right here is where I am having issues. I want this code to turn only certain rows in column A blue if conditions in another column are met.

```
 Dim cell As Range
 Const cutoff = 26223
 For Each cell In Range("Q2:Q41")
 If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value > cutoff Then Cells().Font.Color =      vbBlue
 Next
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

sticking to your original question i.e.

> I want this code to turn only certain rows in column A blue if
>   conditions in another column are met.

you can use this code

```
If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value > cutoff Then Cells(cell.Row,1).Font.Color = vbBlue
```

Comment: That didn't work. Say I wanted to have the color change on Column A, row 2 down to row 41. How would I say it in that?

Comment: That turned that whole range blue. What I want is for excel to test the numbers in column Q2:Q41 and if they are above 30000, then turn the corresponding box in that row for column A blue. Then after that I want anything below 30000 to be red in the corresponding column. For example, say Q2 is 31000 then I want A2 to be highlighted in blue. But Q3 is 28000 then I want A3 to be highlighted in red.

Comment: see edited answer to get back to your _original_ question